# Android, service, детект разблокировки экрана

Tags: android

Здравствуйте!
Пишу приложение, которое детектит разблокировку экрана на устройстве. Как только экран разблокируется -- приложение шлет сигнал на сервер. 
Так вот, как можно детектить разблокировку экрана?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел решение.

```
public class PhoneUnlockedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        if (keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure()) {

            //экран разблочен, логика здесь            

        }
    }
}
```

**Потом добавить это в активити :**

```
registerReceiver(new PhoneUnlockedReceiver(), new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"));
```